# I have an HTML/CSS issue that i cant seem to figure out (beginner level)

Tags: html, css

So i have this test site that i am building and i am having a CSS issue that makes no sense as you will see in the jsfiddle i linked below i have a div which makes up the first big box (class p1 and ps) for some reason my text bar (class tagto with the words COMING SOON) has a margin of about 20px on the top and bottom. There is no reference to a margin in my css that should be doing this i have gone through every line maybe a dozen times and just dont get it so i turn to you people who have helped me many times before. 
If you can please take a quick look and help me out. It would greatly appreciated.

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="one"><h1 class="name">Title of Site</h1></div>
            <div class="one two"><h5 class="tag">Subtext</h5></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="codepen"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="p1 ps">
            <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" >
            <p><h3 class="tagto">COMING SOON</h3></p></div>
        <div class="p2 ps">
            <p class="c2"><h3 class="tagto">COMING SOON</h3></p></div>
        <div class="p3 ps">
            <p class="c3"><h3 class="tagto">COMING SOON</h3></p></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

The CSS is in the jsfiddle because the code block here doesnt format it right.

https://jsfiddle.net/kd2q454c/

Comment: Set `p, h3 {margin:0}` in your CSS to override browser based rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The margin is from the browser rules.  Set:

```
p, h3 {margin:0;}
```

in your CSS to override browser based rules.

Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/d0vws4se/)

Comment: Thanks, i never would have figured that out.

Comment: You're welcome - but you should also look at Brian D's comments below.

Answer (score 1):

The margin is present because of the user agent stylesheet's css on `h3`:

```
h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.17em;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

To override it, just do:

```
h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Due to the fact that the h3 tags are wrapped in paragraph tags (poorly formatted code), this won't solve the problem without also overwriting the default margins on the paragraph tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the wrapping `<p>` tags around the `<h3>` so you have the following code:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="one"><h1 class="name">Title of Site</h1></div>
        <div class="one two"><h5 class="tag">Subtext</h5></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="codepen"></div>
<div>
    <div class="p1 ps">
        <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" >
        <h3 class="tagto">COMING SOON</h3></div>
    <div class="p2 ps">
        <h3 class="tagto">COMING SOON</h3></div>
    <div class="p3 ps">
        <h3 class="tagto">COMING SOON</h3></div>

</div>
```

Then set the `.tagto` class to `margin: 0`

```
.tagto {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 66%;
    height: 25%;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    margin: 0; /* add this line */
}
```

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to remove the `p` tags from around the `h3`s, but it would definitely simplify the code and remove some (currently) unnecessary markup.